# .bat file to extract base system information to CSV

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create an bat script that can extract following basic information from a system to a .CSV file, information I am looking for are Username, Make, Model, SerialNumber, Vendor & OS information.. I manage to do it through a .bat script as below

```
@echo off
cls
wmic computersystem get Username >>sys-info.csv
wmic computersystem get Name, >>sys-info.csv
wmic computersystem get Manufacturer >>sys-info.csv
wmic computersystem get Model >>sys-info.csv
wmic bios get serialnumber >>sys_info.csv
wmic csproduct get vendor >>sys_info.csv
wmic csproduct get name >>sys_info.csv
wmic os get caption >>sys_info.csv
cls
exit
```

though this work, but output csv file is not clean , both the header and the value all are in same column, please suggest what would be best way to do it, I am looking for a csv file with two columns one with description , another one with value

Comment: Please show sample contents of the file `sys_info.csv` and desired contents of that file.

Comment: I can guarantee you that what you have in the output file is not CSV format. To get that type of outpt, I'd suggest you look at some of `WMIC`'s options, for example: `WMIC /Append:sys_info.csv ComputerSystem Get  Manufacturer, Model, Name, Username /Format:CSV`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try for this batch :

```bat
@echo off
Title WMIC INFOS
Set "LogFile=sys_info.csv"
If Exist "%LogFile%" Del "%LogFile%"
wmic /Append:"%LogFile%" os get caption /Format:CSV
wmic /Append:"%LogFile%" computersystem get Username,Name,Manufacturer,Model /Format:CSV
wmic /Append:"%LogFile%" bios get serialnumber /Format:CSV
wmic /Append:"%LogFile%" csproduct get vendor,name /Format:CSV
Start "" "%LogFile%"
```